# react-native-maps 'map.animateToRegion undefined'

Tags: react-native

if i go back to 'HomeScreen' from 'MapScreen' (where the follow function is executed) while its still loading the new region on the MapScreen, it crashes the app with this error:  "map.animateToRegion() is undefined"

this function is on MapScreen:

```
    const updatePosition =  (newPosition) => {
        setShowSelected(null)
        setLoadingMap(true)

        const lat = Number(newPosition.latitude)
        const lon = Number(newPosition.longitude)
        
        let newRegion = {...region}
        newRegion.latitude = lat
        newRegion.longitude = lon

        map.animateToRegion(newRegion, 300)
        setRegion(newRegion)
        setLoadingMap(false)
        props.getCloseShowroom(lat, lon, null, props.accessToken)
}
```

Comment: U r using map.animateToRegion() in Functional Component? Have u define map ref using UseRef() hook...

Comment: If u want map ref then u have to define with using useRef hook...